# getting nafxcwd.lib(timecore.obj) error lnk2001 unresolved external symbol __mbctype after header-include from other project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I made a new project for unittesting with googleTest. I then added a source file from another project to test it. I then got severeal linker errors:

```
  nafxcwd.lib(timecore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __mbctype
  nafxcwd.lib(apphelp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __mbctype
  nafxcwd.lib(filelist.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __mbctype
  nafxcwd.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argv
  nafxcwd.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argc
```

The key options in my projects are:

Testproject:

```
Runtime Library: Multithreaded Debug DLL (necessary for googleTest)
Use of MFC: Shared DLL
```

productive project: (this should actually not matter)

```
  Runtime Library: Multithreaded Debug DLL
  Use of MFC: Use MFC in a static library
```

Even if I copy all the options and files from the productive project with MFC as shared DLL these messages get thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The file, that was imported to the testproject had the "stdafx.h"-include that was resolved to the productive projects one. 
There,

```
#include <afxwin.h>
```

was included. Checking that one turned out, that for shared MFC-DLL, you need to

```
#define _AFXDLL
```

in your project / *before* the afxwin-include. Otherwise you get these errors.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this linker error in VC++ 6 go into `Project Settings => General` and change `Microsoft Foundation Classics` to `Use MFC in a shared dll`. This should solve it for you.